# Shoulder mobility exercises cause pain

Tags: shoulders, mobility, rotator-cuff, shoulder-cuff

I've been rehabbing a case of shoulder impingement for several months now (with a few trips to the physio). The actual *impingement* feels like it is now gone, but I'm having a few mobility issues in that same shoulder.

The main problem being that I can't do back squats without getting pain in my shoulder.

In my most recent trip to the physio, he said I should work on improving the mobility in that shoulder. He said for me to focus on things like rotator cuff stretches (e.g. in a doorway) and wall slides / W-stretches.

But I'm finding that I get a bit of pain just from doing the stretches he gave me. Which is strange because I can do all my back and chest exercises now pain-free. But my shoulder just doesn't seem to agree with anything that requires a lot of mobility.

Could it be that I just need to stretch more gently?

One thing I have noticed however, is that stretching around my anterior deltoid like the below feels pretty good (as though it is what my shoulder has been crying out for):

[image]

I tend to do the above with something to grip my hand on, so that I can stretch it more, rather than just moving my arms behind me

Comment: I had a somewhat similar issue I've been fighting with for a while. I've found that along with wall slides and doorway stretches, wall angels and other back strengthening exercises have helped my shoulder mobility tremendously. Don't forget, it's largely the job of many back muscles to help retract your shoulder. So, strengthening them will probably help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IANA doctor, but I recommend stretching more gently, or simply stretching only to the extent that you need to do so, for example, [to achieve a low-bar back squat position](http://startingstrength.com/training/low-bar-position-stretch).

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on warming up your shoulders before any workout. For this grab a 5 lbs dumbbell (or lighter) vertically, maintain an angle of 90° between biceps and forearms and perform movements for Right hand towards RHS & for left hand towards LHS, perform 10-15 reps.
Then raise your hands to shoulder height(maintaining 90° b/w biceps & forearms) & palm facing down, perform rotation in upward direction for 10-15 reps and then in downward direction for 10-15 reps, maintaining the upper arm aligned with the shoulder and rotating deltoids in proper position.
Do it before any workout for few weeks & see the results.